# Error Resetting not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to renumber points and lines. In the following code, the `Err.Number` is not resetting and the code breaks at 2nd instance of error. How to fix this?

```
S = 0
SS = 0
Surfaces = Y

Do
    SS = SS + 1
Handler:
    S = S + 1

    On Error GoTo Handler

    Set hybridBodyShape1 = hybridBodyShapes1.Item("Line_Extract_" & S)
    hybridBodyShape1.Name = "Line_Extract_" & SS

    Set hybridBodyShape1 = hybridBodyShapes1.Item("Point_Extract_" & S)
    hybridBodyShape1.Name = "Point_Extract_" & SS

    On Error GoTo 0
Loop Until S = Surfaces - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you expect the loop (or your error "handler") to do, but you probably should change the implementation to something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Do
    If Err.Number = 0 Then SS = SS + 1
    Err.Clear
    S = S + 1

    Set hybridBodyShape1 = hybridBodyShapes1.Item("Line_Extract_" & S)
    hybridBodyShape1.Name = "Line_Extract_" & SS

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set hybridBodyShape1 = hybridBodyShapes1.Item("Point_Extract_" & S)
        hybridBodyShape1.Name = "Point_Extract_" & SS
    End If
Loop Until S = Surfaces - 1
On Error GoTo 0
```

The `Err` object doesn't magically reset itself just because you jump to a label in case of an error.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Chip Pearson has a good section on Error Handling: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, once the script throws an error, it is not automatically reset by the fact that you have an error handler enabled.  To properly reset the error, you should have a `Resume` statement somewhere.  Typical error handling routines look like this:

```
Sub ErrorProne()
    Dim i As Integer        
    Dim myArr(4) As Integer

    On Error Goto ErrHndl
    Do While True
        myArr(i) = i    '<-- will bug on 5th iteration
    Loop
PostLoop:
    'More code goes here

Exit Sub

ErrHndl:
    Resume PostLoop
End Sub
```

For a fuller description on how to use Error Handling, see Chip Pearson's site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm